# vBulletin Getting new posts on a particular forum / replies on a thread

Tags: php, sql, vbulletin

I need to get a new replies / forum posts out of a vbulletin forum .

What would be a best manner of fetching it.

Regards,
Azeem

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can fetch new replies / forum posts from database or use the api:

- https://www.vbulletin.com/forum/content.php/352-Method-List
- https://www.vbulletin.com/forum/content.php/363-Thread-Post-Related-Methods

If this is possible with the api i would recommend using the api.

Comment: The api does have a search function search_getnew but no doc available :(

Comment: Is it possible to browse the source of vbulletin? Then it should be possible to see how to use this function.

Comment: The links do not work.  I will upvote if/when links are fixed.

Answer (score 1):

Just figured this one out.

You have to use the API function search_getnew or search_getdaily (I'd recommend search_getdaily, since it is more likely to produce results).

So you make an API call (POST and signed) with api_m = "search_getdaily". If there are any results than you recieve an response array like that:

```
Array
(
[response] => Array
    (
        [errormessage] => search
    )

[show] => Array
    (
        [canviewforums] => 1
        [canviewcalendar] => 1
        [foruminfo] => 
        [threadinfo] => 
        [searchid] => 62
        [notices] => 
        [notifications] => 
    )
)
```

This means that the search was succssfull, and you can call 'search_showresults' to retrieve them actually.

To do this do an api_m = 'search_showresults' (POST and signed) with the 'searchid' you just recieved ('62' in the example).

You don't have to be logged in to do this API call, however then protected forums won't be listed.

Hope this was helpful.

Cheers

Comment: Thank you very much. This is so NOT obvious